# How to send automatic a excel file and picture in KakaoTalk chat using python?

Tags: kakao

I'm new to Python.How to send automatic a excel file and picture in KakaoTalk chat using python? Thanks a lot.
I tried to read Kakao docs, but I don't find anything about this topic. I only found solutions about sending messages to friends or myself
i see a link about it but  Send automatic messages
https://github.com/Xenia101/KakaoTalk-python